# How can I prevent parent component rerender with global state updates and child component rendering?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, rerender

My Header component has notification section where I should display all notifications from global state. As well it has a child which maps all notifications through.
But, the problem is: my parent component gets updated when I don't want it to

I tried using React.memo but it didn't help me. I read about rerender cases but still can't figure out what to do

```
function Header() {
    const { user } = useTypedSelector(state => state.user)
    const { search } = useTypedSelector(state => state.search)
    const { notifications } = useTypedSelector(state => state.notifications)
    const { setSearchValue } = useSearchActions()
    const { userLogout } = useUserActions()
    const navigate = useNavigate()

    return <header className={headerStyles.header}>
        <div className={headerStyles.container}>
            <nav className={headerStyles.nav}>
                <ul className={headerStyles.ul}>
                    <li className={headerStyles.nav_element}>
                        <Notifications />
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
}

export default React.memo(Header)

const Notifications = () => {
    const { notifications } = useTypedSelector(state => state.notifications)

    return (
        <ul>
            {
                Object.values(notifications.chat).map((value: any) => value?.map((message: any, index: any) => <li key={`notification-${index}`}>
                    {message.message}
                </li>))
            }
        </ul>
    )
};

export default React.memo(Notifications)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function Header() {
  const { user } = useTypedSelector((state) => state.user);
  const { search } = useTypedSelector((state) => state.search);
  
  // Rest imports.....
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  return (
    <header className={headerStyles.header}>
      <div className={headerStyles.container}>
        <nav className={headerStyles.nav}>
          <ul className={headerStyles.ul}>
            <li className={headerStyles.nav_element}>
              <MemoizedNotificationsContainer />
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>
  );
}

const MemoizedNotificationsContainer = () => {
    const { notifications } = useTypedSelector((state) => state.notifications);
  
    return <MemoizedNotifications notifications={notifications} />;
  };

const MemoizedNotifications = React.memo(Notifications);


const Notifications = ({ notifications }) => {
  return (
    <ul>
      {Object.values(notifications.chat).map((value: any) =>
        value?.map((message: any, index: any) => (
          <li key={`notification-${index}`}>{message.message}</li>
        ))
      )}
    </ul>
  );
};


export default Header;
export { MemoizedNotificationsContainer as Notifications };
```

I've separated the Notifications component into its own component and container. The Notifications component receives the notifications prop and renders the list of notifications by iterating over the list.

The MemoizedNotificationsContainer component retrieves the notifications from the state using useTypedSelector and passes them as props to the MemoizedNotifications component.

Now, only the Notifications component and its container will re render when the notifications are updated, while the Header component remains unchanged unless its own props change.

Let me know, this is working or not.

Comment: Didn't work unfourtunatelly